# HTML/Js Form running script properly

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, password-protection

I'm working on some HTML for my website. I wanted to make a password page from personal info. This is it:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<center>Password Protection</center>
<p></p>

"Gavin, psst, Gavin. Gavin, psst, Gavin. ______, ______, what? ______, ______, what?" <br><input type="text" id="answer1" value=""><p>
    "This boy thinks that bombs are made of ______!" <br><input type="text" id="answer2" value=""><p>
"I've got many fake books, since I'm a leprechaun farmer who's a ______"<br>
<form onsubmit="return compare()">
<input type="text" id="answer3" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

                        function compare()
                        {
                            var answer11 = "shut up"
                            var answer22 = "cheese"
                            var answer33 = "gambler"
                            var answer1 = document.getElementById("answer1")
                            var answer2 = document.getElementById("answer2")
                            var answer3 = document.getElementById("answer3")
                            if (answer1 == answer11){
                                var question1 = true
                            }
                            if (answer2 == answer22){
                                var question2 = true
                            }
                            if (answer3 == answer33){
                                var question3 = true
                            }
                            if (question1 = true, question2 = true, question3 = true){
                                window.open("webpage name")
                            }
                            else{
                                confirm("Incorrect")
                            }
                        }
                        </script>
<p>
<p>
</html>
```

I finally got the code itself to work partially. Instead of verifying the answers, it just automatically brings you to the webpage when you press the button, even if you didn't enter the right stuff. Any help?

EDIT:

```
        {
                            var answer11 = "shut up"
                            var answer22 = "cheese"
                            var answer33 = "gambler"
                            var answer1 = document.getElementById("answer1")
                            var answer2 = document.getElementById("answer2")
                            var answer3 = document.getElementById("answer3")
                            if (document.getElementById("answer1" == answer11){
                                var question1 = true
                            }
                            if (document.getElementById("answer2").value; == answer22){
                                var question2 = true
                            }
                            if (document.getElementById("answer3").value; == answer33){
                                var question3 = true
                            }
                            if (question1 = true, question2 = true, question3 = true){
                                window.open("www.roadrunnersoccer.com/cole/info/banana.html")
                            }
                            else{
                                confirm("Incorrect")
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
```

Comment: `if (document.getElementById("answer2").value; == answer22)` - remove the `;` (and the same for answer 3). Missing bracket for `answer1`. `if (question1 = true, question2 = true, question3 = true)` those are assignments, not logic tests - use `==` or `===`. Moreover, `question1`, `question2` and `question3` are never defined.

Comment: Thanks, this sorta fixed the problem. I get the incorrect message, but I can't seem to get in with the right password?

Answer (score 2):

```
var answer1 = document.getElementById("answer1").value;
var answer2 = document.getElementById("answer2").value;
var answer3 = document.getElementById("answer3").value;
```

You need to **use value of the element** to compare with string, not the element itself.

Comment: If I understand right, I replace "answer1" with "document.getElementById("answer1").value;", correct? I did so, and now nothing happens at at, except it reloads the page... What did I miss?

Comment: you need to use `return false;` at just before end of your function `compare()`.  so it wont submit the form manually.